# Java - compiler error - enum defined in a class cannot be used for generic substitution in the same class

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have defined a generic interface called `IReport` which takes a generic parameter type `T`

```
public interface IReport<T> {

    public enum ReportType {
        YEARLY, MONTHLY, WEEKLY
    }

    public String getName();

    public ReportType getType();

    public Map<T, List<Cost>> getResults();

}
```

A class is implementing this interface

```
public class WeeklyReport implements IReport<Days> {

    public enum Days {
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Weekly report ";
    }

    @Override
    public ReportType getType() {
        return ReportType.WEEKLY;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Days, List<Cost>> getResults() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you see this, in `WeeklyReport`, `T` is substituted by enum type which is defined in `WeeklyReport` class itself, which is `Days`. For this eclipse is giving compiler error saying

> Days cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

If I use any other enum for generic substitution (which is defined outside this class) then the compiler error disappears. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Maybe define a marker interface `Unit` or whatever and declare the interface as `IReport<T extends Unit>`? Then enums will need to implement that interface, of course

Comment: Also, if I were you, I'd declare `@Override public String toString();` just to be on the safe side ;)

Comment: @fge I tried creating marker interface.. it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a compiler error, because when an external class invokes `WeeklyReport#getResults()` it would expect to get a result of type `Map<Days, List<Cost>>` and the `Days` type will be unknown for the external class.

There's no need to make the nested enum `static`, because nested enums are implicitly `static`. Just refactor the class definition and the `getResults()` method to :

```
public class WeeklyReports implements IReport<WeeklyReports.Days> {
    ..
    public Map<WeeklyReport.Days, List<Cost>> getResults() {
        ...
    }
    ..
}
```

Comment: Cool, just changing the type to `WeeklyReport.Days` worked!. Making the enum  `static` was also not necessary.. Thank you :)

Comment: @sanbhat, ofcourse, my bad. The nested enums are implicitly static by default. I edited the answer and now it makes more sense. :)